# How do i close the validation of the confirm password and roles when edit aspnet user table manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have extend the properties of my aspnetuser tables

However, when i intend to manually edit the data for example

```
var user = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Role == "MerchantSubAccount").ToList();
user[0].Code = "123";
```

when i save the changes, it gave me the below error.

"The Roles field is required."
"The password and confirmation password do not match."

How do i permanent close this validation? I never want to change password or roles, however it force me to give them the value.

Comment: A quick google suggests that it's better to keep additional information on a user in a separate table, then keep a foreign key reference of the Identity user in the new table. See http://www.wou.edu/~morses/classes/cs46x/lecture/Identity.html

Answer (score 0):

On your cshtml page add the

```
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="user.password" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="user.confirmationPassword" />
```

Or C#

```
user.Password= user.Password;
user.ConfirmationPassword=user.ConfirmationPassword;
```